# Angular Excel Import - Not able to get full Date

Tags: excel, angular, date, import

I Have a Excel Import in my Angular App. Its working fine but the only Problem is if the Excel sheet contains a Date I get it like 1/1/97 but when you open the sheet with Excel the Date says 01.01.1997. 
The Problem here is after the Import I dont know the exakt Date like 97 could be 1997, 2097, 2197 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Why you try to use `=year()` instead?